# Find all my posts with links to my website

Tags: discussion, external-links

Moving servers after about a decade, I'm trying to find all my posts at Stack Overflow that included links to my website.

While mostly cruft to be deleted and removed from my posts entirely, there are a few example and informational endpoints that may persist - those urls need updated.

The closest I could find was this Data Explorer query:

- [Vanity search: links to my website posted by other people during last 2 months](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1181/vanity-search-links-to-my-website-posted-by-other-people-during-last-2-months)

Leveraging Google has provided a good base, or I could wait for broken link comments to organically manifest; however, perhaps there is a better method to querying this data?

Comment: If there are a lot of references out there, it's probably best to use the Contact Us link to see if SE can do a find/replace for that URL for you, rather than having you go around bumping a ton of posts just to update a URL.

Comment: That concern had come to mind - looks like 14 posts.

Comment: I'm not sure how many posts you need to edit but if you are almost as important as Jon Skeet you might take this [route](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237110/is-there-any-support-for-mass-link-editing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use advanced search options, specifically the `url:`-operator.

As an example, everything linking to google.com: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Agoogle.com

If you really only want your own posts (I doubt that), add the `user:me`-operator too.

Of course, comments aren't searched this way at all.